# Rviz and rqt crash when trying to save

Tags: kinect, rviz, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have been using rqt-rviz to see the data from my kinect (via openni) but everytime I try to save a file, any kind (image, configuration file,etc.) the "save as..." window opens but it doesnt load nor say anything, just gray. And my ubuntu screen gets darker (like when programs crash). When I type CTRL-C in the terminal I get this error:

```
[ INFO] [1365896813.550288513]: OpenGl version: 3.0 (GLSL 1.3).
python: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
python: /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/recursive_mutex.hpp:92: boost::recursive_mutex::~recursive_mutex(): Assertion `!pthread_mutex_destroy(&m)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60617/rviz-and-rqt-crash-when-trying-to-save/) by [fersarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/3210/fersarr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2013-04-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please file a ticket on https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues, provide your RViz configuration file or list what are the Display types that are active (you might be able to save the config when the Kinect is not running).

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fersarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/3210/fersarr/) on 2013-04-15**:
Thanks, I just did. Also,  just checked, and the error does not happen if I had not launched openni first. But it does happen even if I launch rviz alone (no rqt)